# What addons are common in Garry's mod?

Tags: mods, garrys-mod

I have been playing Garry's mod for a while now, I wonder which addons are used for on a large number of servers or if the community expects more people to have certain mods.

If anyone knows any especially useful mods please link or provide information on them.

Comment: Your question is very subjective as it is, and is likely to be closed - I suggest you rephrase it in a 'what mods can do X?' or 'what should I install if I want to do Y?' format, which will hopefully have specific answers.
I'm sparing you the -1 because it's a rephraseable question ;)

Comment: To clarify what Alex is saying, you need to have a specific problem you're trying to solve (as per the [FAQ]).  Cool/funny/useful/popular aren't good criteria.

Comment: well I put the bit about common. I rather thought it was a better criteria since it is at least a fact whether or not something is used by a majority. what do you think?

Comment: I still think this question is relevant because when I tried joining a Garry's Mod server, I needed to download lots of extra packages that are "commonplace" for other Garry's Mod players. Knowing those things beforehand would really help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The addons that really do "add on" to GMod; that improve it as a sandbox, toolset, and game - the ones I'd consider "essential", are:

- Advanced Duplicator 2
- Wiremod
- The unofficial Wiremod extras pack (UWSVN)
- Fin
- Easy Precision
- Weight
- Buoyancy
- Unbreakable
- Stacker

The less essential but not on the list (due to being too specific or too akward for multiplayer):

- PewPew
- Gravity Hull (Local Physics)
- Advanced Teleporter
- Make Spherical
- Breakable Props
- Door

Google them, make sure to go for the one that looks the most legit, recently updated, and  widely used - generally, if a project has an SVN, then use that as the source rather than downloading a static archive file.

Answer (score 3):

Some common ones that online servers will use are [Wiremod](http://www.wiremod.com/) and PHX. Up until a few months ago, PHX had to be downloaded manually, but now comes with Gmod. Wiremod will help avoid those pesky purple squares on some servers, as well as the absolutely huge download.

I recommend owning and loading Counter-Strike: Source on in the extensions. A HUGE number of servers use CSS content now.

Answer (score 2):

If popularity is a good measure, then you should take a look at available addons sorted by number of downloads : http://www.garrysmod.org/downloads/?a=list&b=downloads

The top 3 right now is:

[Nuke Pack 4
   (official)](http://www.garrysmod.org/downloads/?a=view&id=40859)

[Dismemberment
   Mod](http://www.garrysmod.org/downloads/?a=view&id=52104)

[MP3 Player
   With
   Remixes.zip](http://www.garrysmod.org/downloads/?a=view&id=66787)

---

If you prefer video, there is a video on [Youtube you might find interesting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mv6WmROCGeQ&feature=related). And another video with even [more addons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oT78gyIjoc8).